# Can I add a Parametercollection to another Parametercollection?

Tags: .net, sqldatareader

The `SqlParameterCollection` has an `Add(SqlParameter)` method, and `AddRange(SqlParameter[])` method. Each has several overloads.

Specifically, `SqlCommand.Parameters` is read only, and if I have a `SqlParameterCollection` I can't just assign it, so I want to add it onto the existing collection.

Right now there's a loop in my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
foreach (SqlParameter param in collection)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
}
```

Is there an easy built-in way to add a `SqlParameterCollection` to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set an extension method to make the procedure easier. Haven't found a 'real' way, however:

(Edited re suggestion from @DanielPaoliello)

```
public static void AddCollection(this SqlParameterCollection basic, SqlParameterCollection collection)
{
    foreach (SqlParameter param in collection)
    {
        basic.Add(((param as ICloneable).Clone()) as SqlParameter);
    }
}
```

Than use as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddCollection(collection);
```